# Какая будет скорость работы алгоритма перебора и нахождения числа в массивах на ассемблере?

Tags: ассемблер

Всем доброго дня. Кто знает сколько времени будет занимать для ессемблера примерно такая задача: у нас есть 5 млр массивов по 15 чисел в каждом. Нужно их перебирать и очень быстро находить те массивы в которых присутствует это число. На данный момент я пишу на питоне, объем общий этих массивов будет составлять 180 Гба по предварительным подсчетам. На языках группы Си будет приблизительно max в 100 раз быстрее. А мне нужно что бы минимум в 1000 раз программа работала быстрее. Реально ли это на ессемблере? Я засекал на питоне, например, простейший алгоритм типа:посчитай мне числа от одного до 2,5 млн и выведи на экран, 2,5- миллионое число, комп перебрал за 1 секунду. А нужно что бы хотя бы 2,5 миллиарда за 1 секунду, это реально или нет? И если нет, то примерно сколько будет предел перебора по Вашему мнению. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95487/discussion-on-question-by-st-y-------).

Answer (score 2):

По сути вопроса:
Тест, написанный на компилируемом языке, обрабатывает 128 миллионов целых чисел, проводя с каждым 10 целочисленных операций (в т.ч. делений и модуля) без использования SSE, за 3 секунды на одном ядре i5-4670, за 1.5 на двух, за 0.8 на четырёх, но при этом не требуется особо синхронизировать результаты (это просто некая контрольная сумма). Таким образом, похоже на указанные `pavel` 300 млн простых оп/с на ядро (с хорошим оптимизирующим компилятором будет побыстрее, но не на порядок), миллиард на 4 ядра.

---

Вероятно, будет лучше решать задачу с другой стороны. Алгоритмически более правильно не перелопачивать всю огромную кучу, а сразу выдать нужные массивы. Для этого можно использовать, например, т.н. "[обратный или инвертированный индекс](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81)". Для каждого числа хранится список массивов, в которых он участвует.

Подходит это или нет в Вашем случае - можно судить после уточнения задачи, в частности - нужно знать диапазон или набор чисел.

Answer (score 1):

Это зависит от многих факторов - есть ли какие-то закономерности распределения данных, как эти данные организованы в памяти и т.п. Как правильно подметил MBo, к этому вопросу лучше подойти алгоритмически, а не издержки среды выполнения снижать.

Но первое, что мне пришло в голову - это [векторизация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)). Как мне кажется, задача подходит для этого идеально:

> Есть диапазон от 1 до 32 - основные химические элементы самые часто
>   встречаемые на Земле, обозначенные просто цифрами от 1 до 32. Их
>   максимальное сочетание между собой будет при максимум 16 элементах. То
>   есть имеем 5 миллиардов массивов по 16 чисел из 32 возможных. Нужно
>   будет за 1 секунду находить одно число (оно будет приблизительно
>   встречаться в 120 миллионах случаях), но бегать придётся по 5 млрд
>   массивам.

Вместо обхода и сравнения всех элементов во всех 5 миллиардах массивов, можно разом проверять блок данных на вхождение числа с помощью [SIMD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD)-инструкций:

```
__m128i v_val = _mm_set1_epi8(search_value);
for (int i = 0; i < DATA_SIZE; i += 16) {
    __m128i v_block = *(__m128i*) &data[i];
    int64_t cnt = _popcnt32(_mm_movemask_epi8(_mm_cmpeq_epi8(v_val, v_block)));
    if (cnt > 0) {
        // Элемент найден
    }
}
```

*Пример на C, но сути это не меняет. Да и использование ассемблера при таком подходе заметного прироста производительности не даст.*

Этот пример [SSE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE) позволяет проверять по 16 элементов за раз. Использование [AVX512](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX) позволит проверять по 64 за раз, нужна будет только чуть более сложная проверка, чем на отличие счётчика вхождений от нуля. А ещё лучше, с вашим огромным объёмом данных, использовать GPU, чтобы проверять массивы сразу сотнями.

Comment: Спасибо Сергей за Ваше большое участие в обсуждении  вопроса, будем думать.